# Non-visible data in field

Tags: mysql

The following queries have no results:

```
SELECT * FROM `personal_interest` WHERE LENGTH(`interest`) = 0

SELECT * FROM `personal_interest` WHERE TRIM(`interest`) = ''

SELECT * FROM `personal_interest` WHERE `interest` = ''
```

However this query

```
SELECT * FROM  `personal_interest` WHERE person = 380298
```

has these results:

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

// Edit:

```
SELECT HEX(interest) FROM personal_interest WHERE id = 19496
```

Result:

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot 2]

What could be in the field that my queries do not select it?  What query should I be using?

Comment: Thanks eggyal!  Output is 0D.  Query and screenshot added to post.

Comment: popnoodles - per post TRIM(interest) = '' has no results

Comment: eggyal - so TRIM() does not consider carriage returns to be whitespace?

Comment: It begs the question why do you let the carriage return get in there in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) only removes spaces.  The field could contain other whitespace (such as a tab or newline character) or other non-printing characters.  To see the binary-encoding of the field's content, you can use:

```
SELECT HEX(interest) FROM personal_interest WHERE id = 19496
```

As you can see from the result, your field contains `0x0d`, which is a [carriage return](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/) character.  To select all records that are either blank or contain only whitespace characters, you can use a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT * FROM personal_interest WHERE interest RLIKE '^[[:space:]]*$'
```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely learned something new today!  Appreciate your help!  Will accept answer when SO says I'm allowed!